# A Template to assess a SharePoint environment after Transition?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-migration

I am involved in the process of SharePoint transition of one of the clients to our company which was being managed on their own so far. Now I need to prepare an assessment document on the environment including the impact we can bring in for them.

Could I request you all to provide me a template that I can use to prepare an assessment report or the sites where I can get any of the templates to suffice my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you will get this kind of information. But i would give you some points as per my experience.

1. check the Farm Topology( how many app servers, WFE, SQL Servers), some time customer over loaded or under loaded
2. How big is the environment, in term of Users and Storage
3. What authentication is being Used
4. what is backup & restore strategy
5. what is DR plan
6. what is the up time of the farm
7. what services applications configured
8. what is purpose of sharepoint farm?
9. what method is being used Monitoring of farm
10. Analyze the ULS logs /Event Log to get any potential threats.
11. Analyze the IIS logs for traffic.
12. data protection
13. how much they spending to maintain the farm

Check this link, may be help you http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758645(v=office.15).aspx
.

Comment: Thanks for your input brother..... I have gather almost all of the above mentioned details, need to document them in a proper manner for which I thought if someone like you could help me with.... But really appreciate your inputs here...!!!